# Replacing a substring of a variablename of a string with a variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace, substring

I have a variable, called String that has a tag in it called bar.`var String = "Foo <Object.1>"` and I have an object called Object, `var Object = {1:"Bar",2:"More Bar",3:"Even more Bar"}`, and now I need the tag Object.1 to get replaced by the  so I end up with something like this:`var String = "Foo Bar"`

Here is the catch: I might have multiple (and different) tags in one string, and I never know which and how many tags I have in that string, and also there could be millions of variables inside of the object.

Calls for help,
Luca

Comment: I am pretty sure `Object` is already used for a generic object, I think you should rename your variable.

Comment: As is `String` for sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use, with proper variable names and a global variable for the replacment object, [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with an access over the `window` object and keys, taken from the string.

```js
var string = "Foo <object.1>",
    object = { 1: "Bar", 2: "More Bar", 3: "Even more Bar" };

string = string.replace(/<([^.]+)\.([^>]+)>/, function (_, v, k) {
    return window[v][k];
});

console.log(string);
```

A better approach, would be to store the replacement parts into an object and take the parts as keys, without using the `window` object. Then the object could be local as well.

```js
var string = "Foo <object.1>",
    values = { object: { 1: "Bar", 2: "More Bar", 3: "Even more Bar" } };

string = string.replace(/<([^.]+)\.([^>]+)>/, function (_, k1, k2) {
    return values[k1][k2];
});

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.prototype.replace()` function:

```js
var str = "Foo <Object.1> some text, <Object.2> data, <Object.3> other",
    values = {1:"Bar", 2:"More Bar", 3:"Even more Bar"};

str = str.replace(/<Object\.(\d+)>/g, function (m0, m1) {
  return (values[m1])? values[m1] : m0;  // replace if `Object` number exists as a key of predefined `values` object
});

console.log(str);
```